# Custom list, task list?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list

I have an excel file with information of hotels and their managers within a certain city. Here is what I need to do:

I *think* i need a custom list (or maybe contact app) that lists:

- All active hotels within the city (name, address, Phone, etc)
- All the active managers within the city
- Which hotel they work for
- Manager Permit expiration dates
- Permit number (this can be sequential assigned in sharepoint)
- Status of permit (temporary, approved, denied, revocation, expired - would like expired to be based of date of expiration and be done automatically)
- The ability to add pictures of each manager would be nice.

Is this something that is even possible in SharePoint ?

If someone comes and asks me if someone has a valid permit, I'd like the ability to just do a search on their name and have it show all hotels they have worked at as well as all past and current managers.

With the same information above, I also would like to create a task or pending list. Basically when an application is received, 5 separate referrals are created. The permit is considered temporary until all referrals are returned and the permit goes to a committee for approval, denial, etc. I want to be able to track when the referrals are sent to each department/organization, and track when they are received. Once all are received, then I can send it to the committee for a decision. I'd like to be able to run a monthly report that shows which referrals are still needed and for which hotels/managers. Is this something that can possibly be accomplished with the task list ?

Answer (score 0):

for the above scenrio you need to create 3 lists 
1. Managers 
2. Hotels
3. Manager - Hotel Info

For 1st list - Managers 
Create custom list with required information

1. Permit number
2. Name of Manager
3. Active Managers (keep a check box / dropdown to set Active / inactive)
4. Manager Permit expiration dates
5. Status of permit (temporary, approved, denied, revocation, expired) - Set calculated field based on Manager Permit expiration date or to be set manually.
6. Picture field to set manager image

For 2nd list - Hotel
Make master list of hotels with information

1. Name
2. Address
3. etc.

For 3rd List create custom list with following fields

1. Manager
2. List item
3. this will be lookup to Manager list - Manager Name
4. Hotel Worked For - this will be lookup to hotel list - hotel name
5. Start Date
6. End Date
7. Comments
8. Status (Active / Past )

To search & show info for managers

1. On site page, add Manager web part, Manager - Hotel list webpart. Next make connection between the 2 based on Manager name
2. On Manager list - display form : Edit the page, add Manager-Hotel Info webpart, make connection to show items based on Manager name / id.

Hope that servers your purpose.